# Are we also shifting the mantissa in the fast inverse square root?

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, computer-science

I've read this blog about the algorithm:

http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/

I understand that we have to manipulate the exponent in order to obtain the inverse square root. To this manipulation we take advantage from the IEEE 754 notation. My problem comes in this sentence (almost at the end) of the article:

"So, the code converts the floating-point number into an integer. It then shifts the bits by one, which means the exponent bits are divided by 2"

I we do that we are also manipulating the mantissa. Why we're doing this? As I said, the idea is to manipulate the exponent so, why we are also changing the mantissa? Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You number is $x=2^{e-b}·(1+m)$ where $e$ is the exponent, $b$ the bias, $m$ the mantissa interpreted as fractional part. The inverse square root of this is
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x}}=2^{(b-e)/2}·(1-m/2+O(m^2))
$$
This shows you why the bit shift in the floating point number will come close to that result and also why you need to subtract it from a "magic" number, since the negated bit shift alone produces something like (but not exactly)
$$
-2^{b+2-e/2}·(1-m/2)
$$

---

To test this, compute the magic constant by reverse engineering the formula:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
    float x=1;
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<20; k++) {
        int i = *(int*)&x;
        float y = 1/sqrtf(x);
        int j = *(int*)&y;
        printf("x=%.20e : magic=%X\n",x,(i>>1)+j);
        x *= 1.06;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with result

```
x=1.00000000000000000000e+00 : magic=5F400000
x=1.05999994277954101562e+00 : magic=5F3C7D3B
x=1.12359988689422607422e+00 : magic=5F396B7A
x=1.19101583957672119141e+00 : magic=5F36CCBA
x=1.26247680187225341797e+00 : magic=5F34A33A
x=1.33822536468505859375e+00 : magic=5F32F17E
x=1.41851890087127685547e+00 : magic=5F31BA4E
x=1.50363004207611083984e+00 : magic=5F3100C3
x=1.59384787082672119141e+00 : magic=5F30C841
x=1.68947875499725341797e+00 : magic=5F311480
x=1.79084753990173339844e+00 : magic=5F31E98F
x=1.89829838275909423828e+00 : magic=5F334BD6
x=2.01219630241394042969e+00 : magic=5F34DC35
x=2.13292813301086425781e+00 : magic=5F338AA4
x=2.26090383529663085938e+00 : magic=5F329A82
x=2.39655804634094238281e+00 : magic=5F320E46
x=2.54035162925720214844e+00 : magic=5F31E8A8
x=2.69277262687683105469e+00 : magic=5F322C9E
x=2.85433888435363769531e+00 : magic=5F32DD67
x=3.02559924125671386719e+00 : magic=5F33FE87
```

The magic constant used in the program, `5f3759df`, is in the middle of that following some error minimization strategy or some other.

Comment: How do you obtain [math] (1-m/2+O(m^{2})) [/math] ? This suppose to be [math] sqrt(1+m) [/math] isn't it? Thanks

Comment: This is for $(1+m)^{-1/2}=1+(-1/2)·m+(-1/2)·(-1/2-1)/2·m^2+…$. `$1/\sqrt{1+m}$` gives $1/\sqrt{1+m}$.

Comment: Thanks for aswering. Then we're also shifting the mantisa isn't it? I say it because of the m/2

Comment: Yes. And the last bit of the exponent gets shifted into the mantissa, leading to - to me at least - unknown effects.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Excuse me but how do you obtain [math] −2^{b−e/2}⋅(1−m/2)[/math]? I understand that this is the result of: magic_number - [math] (1-m/2+O(m^{2})) [/math]. Is that so?

Comment: I'm not actually sure that that is correct. The shift leads to `e/2` in the exponent bits and thus `e/2-b` as exponent. Negation gives `(2b+2)-e/2` in the exponent bits, remember the bias is `b=127` and the modulus/wrap-around is `2^8=256=2b+2`. Thus the actual negated exponent is `b+2-e/2`. But that does not really matter, the difference goes into the magic number.

Comment: For a general construction principles for such approximations, that includes the reciprocal square root as one particular sub-case, see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042673/optimized-low-accuracy-approximation-to-rootnx-n)

Comment: I think we use the magic number to reach 2 things: Firstly we negate the shiftet i.e. (divided by two) exponent and secondly we do a first adjustment to the mantissa to not to lose to much "information". Is that right? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that in IEEE 754, the leading "1" in the mantissa is implicit -- it appears nowhere in the binary representation of the number.  Consequently, if $M$ is the represented part of the mantissa and $e$ is the exponent, the represented number is $\left( 1+\frac{M}{2} \right) \times 2^{-e}$.  As the other answer notes, $\sqrt{1+\frac{M}{2}} \approx 1+\frac{M}{4}$, which is the new mantissa when the represented part is shifted.